# The requested operation is not supported on forward only result sets Sql server hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

So i have a query that works fine but when i want to visit the second page of the results i get this exception:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException:The requested operation is not supported on forward only result sets 
Caused by : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The requested operation is not supported on forward only result sets
```

Here is my code

```
HibernatePage sp = new HibernatePage(pageNumber, pageSize);
sp.scrollableResults = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
sp.totalElements = sp.calculateTotalElementsByList(query); 
sp.determineElements(query);
```

with determineElement(query)

```
private void determineElements(Query query) throws HibernateException {

    if (Integer.MAX_VALUE == this.pageNumber)
          this.pageNumber = (getTotalNumberOfElements() / this.pageSize);

   elements = query.setFirstResult((this.pageNumber * this.pageSize)-this.pageSize).setMaxResults(this.pageSize + 1).list();
      }
```

I'm using `hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect`

Her is the stacktrace

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: The requested operation is not supported on forward only result sets 
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.java:108)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.absolute(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.advance(Loader.java:1651)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1982)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2463)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2449)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2279)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2274)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1115)
        at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
        at ma.softwork.commons.dao.impl.HibernatePage.determineElements(HibernatePage.java:205)
        at ma.softwork.commons.dao.impl.HibernatePage.getScrollPageInstanceWithTotalByList(HibernatePage.java:180)
        at ma.softwork.commons.dao.impl.HibernatePage.getHibernatePageInstance(HibernatePage.java:127)
        at ma.softwork.commons.dao.impl.HibernatePage.getHibernatePageInstance(HibernatePage.java:116)
        at ma.softwork.dao.impl.QueryBuilderFactory.rechercheContratsPagination(QueryBuilderFactory.java:332)
        at ma.per.service.contrat.ContratService.rechercheContratsPagination(ContratService.java:250)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Am i missing something ?

Comment: Did you ever find out a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error if the value of below expression is negative, let say ***this.pageNumber is 0***, then value of below expression can be negative

```
(this.pageNumber * this.pageSize)-this.pageSize
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like not all the Hibernate SQL Server Dialect versions are using scrollable resultsets on its own to make pagination work.

If you use standard dialect, you are using a 2000 version.

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
```

Using a newer version as this one could solve the issue.

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect" />
```